# Not cropping the selected area

Tags: jquery, jcrop

Now comes the cropping part: Shows a different part of the image with the correct width, height.

Area to be cropped

[image]

Cropped Area
[image]

Heres my js code

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery('#imgCrop').Jcrop({

                onSelect: storeCoords,
                onChange: storeCoords 


            });

        });

      function storeCoords(c) {

    jQuery('#X').val(c.x);

    jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);

    jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
    jQuery('#H').val(c.h);

  };

protected void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string ImageName = Session["WorkingImage"].ToString();

    int w = Convert.ToInt32(W.Value);

    int h = Convert.ToInt32(H.Value);

    int x = Convert.ToInt32(X.Value);

    int y = Convert.ToInt32(Y.Value);



    byte[] CropImage = Crop(path + ImageName, w, h, x, y);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length))
    {

        ms.Write(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length);

        using (SD.Image CroppedImage = SD.Image.FromStream(ms, true))
        {

            string SaveTo = path + "crop" + ImageName;

            CroppedImage.Save(SaveTo, CroppedImage.RawFormat);

            pnlCrop.Visible = false;

            pnlCropped.Visible = true;

            imgCropped.ImageUrl = "images/crop" + ImageName;

        }

    }

}
static byte[] Crop(string Img, int Width, int Height, int X, int Y)
{

    try
    {

        using (SD.Image OriginalImage = SD.Image.FromFile(Img))
        {

            using (SD.Bitmap bmp = new SD.Bitmap(Width, Height))
            {

                bmp.SetResolution(OriginalImage.HorizontalResolution, OriginalImage.VerticalResolution);

                using (SD.Graphics Graphic = SD.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {

                    Graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    Graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                    Graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                    Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage, new SD.Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), X, Y, Width, Height, SD.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                    bmp.Save(ms, OriginalImage.RawFormat);

                    return ms.GetBuffer();

                }

            }

        }

    }

    catch (Exception Ex)
    {

        throw (Ex);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You're going to have to explain this better. What's your question? What have you tried? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to crop the image. But the selection part doesn't work. If u look at the attachment, the leaf is the selected part, but it shows me some part of the image. I tried changing some parameters in this line of the code. Graphic.DrawImage(OriginalImage, new SD.Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), X, Y, Width, Height, SD.GraphicsUnit.Pixel

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue once and I cannot remember exactly now but i think you have to set the `boxWidth` option in the jCrop especially if you are not showing the original size of the image (The image is actually 1024x768 but you style your cropper to 350x350)

Also you might have to set the `aspectRatio` for jCrop even if it is `0` or `1` because it needs to recalculate the dimensions based on the image size.
Also makes sure to use the latest version 0.9.9 (as of this post) and check inside the JavaScript if it is actually 0.9.9 because some times he does not update the links properly.. It caught me out...

I think your server code is OK- But you need to inspect what are the number getting set in the hidden fields so that you can debug the issue.