# Is it possible to crop a part of image with jcrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I want a part of the image become   crop-able with jcrop by specifying  X and Y co-ordinates. is it possible?

Comment: I would assume that a library called `jcrop` would allow one to crop

Comment: Below link May help  you what you trying to do . 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797200/not-cropping-the-selected-area